# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Desired Capabilities must be a dictionary PYTHON 3

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello i got this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\email-account-generator-master\EmailAccountGenerator.py", line 40, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities);
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 139, in __init__
    raise WebDriverException("Desired Capabilities must be a dictionary")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Desired Capabilities must be a dictionary
```

My code problem probably :

```
service = service.Service(r'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\email-account-generator-master\chromedriver.exe');
service.start()
capabilities = {'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',}

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities);
```

Comment: you have provided applications path instead of chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> type({'a'})
<class 'set'>
>>> type({'a':'b'})
<class 'dict'>
```

`{'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',}` is a set not a dict